# How to pass value as index in Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to pass value as index?

I have tried:

```
- hosts:
  vars:
    var1: 2
    var2: "{{ data[{{var1}}]}}"
```

Is there a way for me to achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the variable in the index

```yaml
  data:
    1: A
    2: B
  var1: 2
  var2: "{{ data[var1] }}"
```

The debug task

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: var2
```

will display the variable

```yaml
  var2: B
```

---

**Index must be an integer**

If the index is a string, .e.g

```yaml
  var1: '2'
```

The variable is undefined

```yaml
  var2: "{{ data[var1] }}"
```

and the *debug* task reports

|   var2: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

You can convert the index to an integer to be always on the save side. The expression below gives correct value for both integer and string in the variable *var1*.

```yaml
  var2: "{{ data[var1|int] }}"
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, do you remember answering my previous question about sequential value in different host in the same group host?

i tried using those sequential value to pass it as index and i was wondering why the value from the sequential value is undefined when i tried. do you perhaps have any idea?

Comment: turns out the sequential_value is a string and not integer thats why it failed

Comment: Right. The index must be an integer. I updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: it's still undefined, is it additional template or is it provided by ansible?